YML How to specify python 3.10
I want to start matrix testing for my code. I try running unit test using the yml below on Azure Devops pipelines.
When I run it, it shortens "3.10" to "3.1". How do I avoid that? 
parameters:
  - name: imageList
    type: object
    default: ["windows-latest", "ubuntu-latest", "windows-2019", "ubuntu-20.04"]
  - name: pythonList
    type: object
    default:
      - "3.11"
      - "3.10" # WHAT TO DO HERE
      - "3.9"

stages:
  - stage: test_on_microsoft_hosted_agents
    jobs:
      - ${{ each image in parameters.imageList }}:
        - job: ${{ replace(replace(image, '-', '_'), '.', '_') }}
          pool:
            vmImage: ${{ image }}
          strategy:
            maxParallel: 1
            matrix:
              ${{ each python in parameters.pythonList }}:
                Python${{ replace(python, '.', '') }}:
                  python.version: "${{ python }}"
                  platform.name: "${{ image }}"
          steps:
            - task: UsePythonVersion@0
              inputs:
                versionSpec: "$(python.version)"
              displayName: "Use Python $(python.version)"


Hi guys, The behavior seemed to be reported here. Would you consider temporarily using @RuiJarimba's workaround at the moment? Appreciate your insights and efforts, Rui.

The behavior seemed to be reported here. I also tried to use split() function but it didn't seem to work as replace() as suggested by @RUI.
Since the versionSpec property of the UsePythonVersion@0 uses SemVer's version range syntax,

A leading "=" or "v" character is stripped off and ignored.

Thus, we can use v3.10 as the python version in the UsePythonVersion task directly.
parameters:
  - name: imageList
    type: object
    default: ["windows-latest", "ubuntu-latest", "windows-2019", "ubuntu-20.04"]
  - name: pythonList
    type: object
    default:
    - 'v3.11'
    - 'v3.10' # WHAT TO DO HERE
    - 'v3.9'

stages:
  - stage: test_on_microsoft_hosted_agents
    jobs:
      - ${{ each image in parameters.imageList }}:
        - job: ${{ replace(replace(image, '-', '_'), '.', '_') }}
          pool:
            vmImage: ${{ image }}
          strategy:
            maxParallel: 10
            matrix:
              ${{ each python in parameters.pythonList }}:
                Python${{ replace(python, '.', '') }}:
                  python.version: ${{python}} # Use v3.x directly
                  platform.name: ${{ image }}
          steps:
            - script: |
                echo $(python.version)

            - task: UsePythonVersion@0
              inputs:
                versionSpec: '$(python.version)'
              displayName: Use Python $(python.version)



Hi @VitaminC, This answer provides supplementary information on the UsePythonVersion task usage. Please feel free to refer to RUI's answer as the primary solution. Thx for your sharing to benefit other community members who may have the same concerns. We also appreciate @RUI's continued efforts. Wish you guys have a relaxing weekend.

"we can use v3.10 as the python version in the UsePythonVersion task directly" - cool :-)

This is a dirty workaround, but consider adding a prefix to the version number to force it to be treated as a string, instead of a number.
Instead of:
parameters:
  - name: pythonList
    type: object
    default:
      - "3.11"
      - "3.10"
      - "3.9"

Do:
parameters:
  - name: pythonList
    type: object
    default:
      - "v3.11"
      - "v3.10"
      - "v3.9"

Prefix v can be easily removed when setting the version in UsePythonVersion@0 task.
Example
trigger: none

parameters:
  - name: imageList
    type: object
    default: 
      - windows-latest
      - ubuntu-latest
      - windows-2019
      - ubuntu-20.04
  - name: pythonList
    type: object
    default:
      - v3.11
      - v3.10
      - v3.9

stages:
  - stage: test_on_microsoft_hosted_agents
    jobs:
      - ${{ each image in parameters.imageList }}:
        - job: ${{ replace(replace(image, '-', '_'), '.', '_') }}
          pool:
            vmImage: ${{ image }}
          strategy:
            maxParallel: 1
            matrix:
              ${{ each python in parameters.pythonList }}:
                Python${{ replace(python, '.', '') }}:
                  python.version: "${{ replace(python, 'v', '') }}" # <--------------- remove 'v' from version
                  platform.name: "${{ image }}"
          steps:
            - task: UsePythonVersion@0
              inputs:
                versionSpec: "$(python.version)"
              displayName: "Use Python $(python.version)"

Running the pipeline:


I try avoiding as much formatting etc work in azure pipelines as possible as it can get cursed, its typically easier (from my experience) to scan the parameter and then toggle a classic matrix based on those values.
The way I would implement this python versioning strategy is as follows:
parameters:
  # as is
...
strategy:
  matrix:
    ${{ if contains(parameters.pythonList, '3.8') }}: 
      Python38:
        python.version: '3.8'
    ${{ if contains(parameters.pythonList, '3.9') }}: 
      Python39:
        python.version: '3.9'
    ${{ if contains(parameters.pythonList, '3.10') }}: 
      Python310:
        python.version: '3.10'
    ${{ if contains(parameters.pythonList, '3.11') }}: 
      Python311:
        python.version: '3.11'
    ${{ if contains(parameters.pythonList, '3.12') }}: 
      Python312:
        python.version: '3.12'
...
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  displayName: 'Use Python Version: $(python.version)'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '$(python.version)'

This also removes all the formatting and splitting malarky, and is the way azure recommends handling this versioning stuff
